# RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter not work after upgrade to 20.04 lts

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

I have notebook Lenovo E490, which has Wi-Fi RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wi-Fi adapter, but after upgrade to 20.04 LTS, Wi-Fi not working. Has anyone experienced this problem?

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 64:1c:67:ae:26:49
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-generic
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 00
       serial: 50:5b:c2:b4:5f:29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.3.0-51-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.15.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff
```

The icon appears in the upper corner but I cannot complete the scan of available networks to connect.

When running the command `nmcli device wifi list`, "No device or network" appears.

When running `sudo iwlist wlp5s0 scan`, the result is:

```
wlp5s0  No scan results
```

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us in greater detail what you mean by "wifi not working." You have an associated driver, a wireless interface and an apparent internet connection. You have an IP address. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: When you are actually already connected, click on the name of the network to which you are connected and a drop-down should appear that says, *Select Network*. When you click on that, after a few moments, a list of networks will appear. Are you saying that you've done that but none appear? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: How about the old way? `sudo iwlist wlp5s0 scan`